# Enable email enumeration protection on tenant

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-identity

I am referring to the [Enable Email Enumeration Protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection) feature. I see that this in fact works for the project-native tenant (None tenant). However, the configuration does not propagate to the tenants within the same project. Is there a way to specify a tenant and enable the same thing on a targeted tenant?

Replication method:

1. Create a project
2. Enable Identity Platform
3. Enable multitenancy, create a tenant
4. create a user under project directly, as well as inside the tenant
5. enable the Enumeartion Protection via the REST API ([link](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection))
6. Login with wrong credentials on either accounts, shows different message.